# Deploying Lambda + API-gateway + CloudFront through serverless framework at a time

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I want to deploy `Lambda` + `API-gateway` + `CloudFront` through `serverless framework`.

`Lambda` and `API-gateway` can be deployed by defining `function` in `serverless.yml` and for `CloudFront` I define `resources`.

However, for `CloudFront`, I had to define `DomainName` attribute which should be filled with `API-gateway` endpoint that is not yet deployed.

```
Resources:
  ApiDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - Id: ApiGateway
          DomainName: "api-gateway endpoint"
```

As the result, I have to follow the steps.

1. Deploy `Lambda` + `API-gateway`.
2. Check `API-gateway` endpoint.
3. Add `CloudFront` resource into `serverless.yml` with `DominName` attribute pointing to `API-gateway` endpoint.
4. Deploy `CloudFront`.

Is there any way to deploy all(`CloudFront` + `API-gateway` + `Lambda`) at a time?
(But I don't want to give `API-gateway` DNS)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `serverless-api-cloudfront` which automatically creates properly configured AWS CloudFront distribution that routes traffic to API Gateway. To use it, it's simple, you have to install it using `npm i --save-dev serverless-api-cloudfront`, after that you have to add in your `serverless.yml` file:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-api-cloudfront

custom:
  apiCloudFront:
    domain: my-custom-domain.com
    certificate: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:000000000000:certificate/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444
    waf: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    compress: true
    logging:
      bucket: my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
      prefix: my-prefix
    cookies: none
    headers:
      - x-api-key
    querystring:
      - page
      - per_page
```

If you which to understand how it works, and other possible configurations, you may visit their [Github's](https://github.com/Droplr/serverless-api-cloudfront) page.

Comment: It still looks to have to put api-gateway endpoint into `domain` attribute in your example. right? How could I know API-gateway endpoint that is not yet deployed?

Comment: @SangminKim The `domain` value should be your custom domain, not the endpoint provided my API Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to any resources created by serverless using the same way you would refer them in cloudformation.

Serverless framework creates the cloudformation template to deploy
- Sls package 
- cd .serverless
- cat cloudformation-template-update-stack.json

You can get the name of the resource that sls creates for you

```
DomainName:
            Fn::Join:
              - "."
              - - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
              - execute-api
              - - Ref: AWS::Region
              - amazonaws.com
```